# how to include from differing directory paths and depth

Tags: php, path, directory

i am trying to include the same connect.php file as a part of the nav.php file throughout multiple different directories and directory depth's with a generic 'dynamic' substitute for the include path back to the connect.php file in the website root folder eg.

> www.mywebsite.com/shop/shoes/sandals/index.php

and

> www.mywebsite.com/shop/shoes/sandals/index.php

etc.

with the connect.php file being located in the root directory

> www.mywebsite.com/connect.php

the code I am currently using in the nav.php (which is included in all pages and directories that are accessible by users)is as follows.

```
<?php
include '../../connect.php';    
?>
```

however this will obviously not work in directory paths like

> www.mywebsite.com/shop/shoes/sandals/index.php

I have no previous experience making a single connect.php file accessible by multiple directory paths using an absolute path with php.
however some guidance on this matter would be extremely helpful.
Thanks

Comment: you are going 2 path back make it 3 ../../../ let me know if that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using something like

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/connect.php";
```

[To continue reading...](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Hope this helps!

Comment: If this answer resolved your problem, could you mark it as accepted by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer? It helps the community know that this question has been resolved. Thanks!